# worker.port.on doesn't get events

Tags: javascript, event-handling, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

`main.js` complete code:

```
const data = require("self").data;
const pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("addButtons.js"),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
        worker.port.on("testEvent", function(name) {
            window.alert(name);
        });
     }
});
```

`addButtons.js`, extract:

```
<...>
var img=document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute('src', '...');                  
     img.onclick=function() { 
            var name='printMe';
            self.port.emit("testEvent", name);
        //  window.alert(name);
        }
<...>
```

The goal is to send event from `addButton.js` to `main.js` by clicking to img and show alert with argument. If I uncomment  line `//window.alert(name);` in `addButton.js` - I'll get the alert, i.e. `onclick` function works fine. But described above code doesn't show me alert or any errors in console. 
I have read all concerning documentation but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The event is sent fine - it's simply that there is no `window` and consequently no `window.alert()` in your extension (if you open Error Console by pressing Ctrl-Shift-J you should see this error). You can only use `window.alert()` in content scripts because they are attached to a web page, in extension modules you should use [`console.log()`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/dev-guide/addon-development/console.html) instead.

Comment: @gvidik: Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask.

Comment: @gvidik, it's worth noting that none of the normal document apis are available by default in main.js.